# Working with XML in a Firefox Add-on(ex Jetpack)

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-5

I'm currently developing a Firefox add-on(using https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/ ) that consumes an API where the return data is in xml.

My problem is that I need to parse the returned data, and would like to do that using a xml object.

Since the request module only supports JSON and Text ( https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html#Response ) I need to convert the response.text to XML.
The code looks like this:

```
var Request = require('request').Request  
.......
var req = Request({
        url: https://to-the-api.com,
        content: {
          op: 'get-the-data-op',
          password: "super-sec",
          user: "username"
        },
        onComplete: function (response) {

         dataAsText = response.text;
         console.log("output: " + dataAsText);
        }
    });
    req.post();
```

I have tried to user (new DOMParser).parseFromString(response.text, 'text/xml') but unfortunately it just fails with a error like ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined

The question is if anyone of you guys have been able to create a Xml object inside a Firefox add-on, and if so, how?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171590/how-to-parse-a-xml-string-in-a-firefox-addon-using-add-on-sdk/13089414#13089414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use a normal XMLHttpRequest if you want to process the response as XML?

Comment: Yeah, why did I not think about that...Thanks a lot. 
The `XMLHttpRequest` surly have some limitations compared to the `Request`object, but I do think this solution will do for me...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the capability to parse response as xml was present, but has been removed. [check out this bugzilla reference](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=611042)

Answer (score 0):

If `DOMParser` is unavailable you can try [E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/e4x):

```
var xml = new XML(response.text);
alert(xml.children().length());
```

Comment: Unfortunately I forgot to say that I have tried new XML but without luck. Code like:  
    `x = new XML('<el><unread_count><count>0</count></unread_count><notification><id>123</id><type>0</type><post>456</post></notification></el>');
    console.log(x)`

Just ends up in errors like:

`error: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: can't wrap XML objects`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `XMLHttpRequest` object to handle your xhr request.  Then when you get a response back access the `responseXML` object of the `request` variable.  In the `responseXML` you'll have the `documentElement` and can use the `querySelectorAll` or `querySelector` to find elements you want.  In each element you want just grab the `textContent` you need.

Here's an example to get you going (this looks for the 'xmls' element in the response):

```
var request = new require("xhr").XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://to-the-api.com', true);
request.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
     if(request.status == 200) {
      var xmls = request.responseXML.documentElement.querySelectorAll("xmls");
      for (var i = 0; i < xmls.length; i++) {
        console.log("xml", i, xmls[i], xmls[i].textContent);
      }
     }
     else {
       console.log('Error', request.responseText);
     }
  }
};
request.send(null);
```