# How to parse a XML string in a Firefox addon using Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, domparser

I am trying to create a FF AddOn that brings some XML data from a website. But I can't find a way to parse my RESPONSE. First I used DOMParser but I get this error:

> ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined.

Someone suggested to use XMLHttpRequest, because the parsing is done automatically but then I get this other error:

> Error: An exception occurred. Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "resource://jid0-a23vmnhgidl8wlymvolsst4ca98-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/cuddlefish.js",
>   line 208, in require
>       let module, manifest = this.manifest[base], requirer = this.modules[base]; TypeError: this.manifest is undefined

I really don't know what else to do. I must note that I am using the AddOn Builder to achieve this.

Below the code that doesn't seem to work.

Option 1:

```js
exports.main = function() {

require("widget").Widget({
    id: "widgetID1",
    label: "My Mozilla Widget",
    contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
    onClick: function(event) {

    var Request = require("request").Request;
    var goblecontent = Request({
      url: "http://www.myexperiment.org/search.xml?query=goble",
      onComplete: function (response) {
        var parser = new DOMParser(); 
        var xml = parser.parseFromString(response.text, "application/xml");  

        var packs = xml.getElementsByTagName("packs");
        console.log(packs);
      }
    });

    goblecontent.get();

    }
});

};
```

Option 2:

```js
exports.main = function() {
    require("widget").Widget({
        id: "widgetID1",
        label: "My Mozilla Widget",
        contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
        onClick: function(event) {

            var request = new require("xhr").XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", "http://www.myexperiment.org/search.xml?query=goble", false);
            request.send(null);  

            if (request.status === 200) {  
              console.log(request.responseText);  
            }  
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`DOMParser` constructor isn't defined in the context of SDK modules. You can still get it using [chrome authority](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) however:

```js
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var parser = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/domparser;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMParser);
```

[`nsIDOMParser` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIDOMParser).

That said, your approach with `XMLHttpRequest` should work as well. You used the `new` operator incorrectly however, the way you wrote it a new "require object" is being created. This way it should work however:

```js
var {XMLHttpRequest} = require("xhr");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Please consider using an asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest` object however, use `request.onreadystatechange` to attach your listener (the `xhr` module currently doesn't support other types of listeners or `addEventListener`).

Comment: +1 for the sake of your users please avoid synchronous network access of any kind!

Comment: @canuckistani: Now if only `xhr` implemented proper `onload` and `onevent` properties ;) Web developers might be used to `onreadystatechange` but I consider it an ugly solution.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant. The DOMParse solution worked great. However the XMLHttpRequest solution threw at me the same error message. I ended up doing something similar to what you recommended me with DOMParse: `var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome"); var request = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);` and it worked!. Thank you

Comment: @user1042066: Please don't do this. `xhr` module makes sure that the request is automatically aborted if your extension is uninstalled/disabled - the regular `XMLHttpRequest` won't do anything like this.

Comment: @Wladimir Palant . I won't do that sorry. I found my mistake I copied the code you posted blindly without removing the `new` operator. Now it worked! thank you

Comment: @kriztean: Ouch... You are right, the SDK consistently uses factory functions instead of the `new` operator and I completely missed that. Fixed my answer now.

Comment: From the [xhr module docs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/api-utils/xhr.html): _XMLHttpRequest(): Creates an XMLHttpRequest. This is a constructor, so its use should always be preceded by the new operator._ I have tested it and for me it doens't work if I don't use the new keyword. I get a _TypeError: null is not extensible_ error in xhr.js _this._req = req_. So correct way: `var xhr = require("xhr"); var req = new xhr.XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: @cprcrack: You are right, I fixed the code. I think that this changed since the answer was written (it's an internal API so it can change at any time).

Answer (score 3):

If you use `XMLHttpRequest` (available via the [xhr module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/api-utils/xhr.html)) you can easily avoid the use of `DOMParser`. Bellow I provide an example supposing `request` is an `XMLHttpRequest` object which request is successfully completed:

**Instead of:**

```
var parser = new DOMParser(); 
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(request.responseText, "application/xml");
```

**Use:**

```
var xmlDoc = request.responseXML;
```

**An then you can:**

```
var packs = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("packs");
console.log(packs);
```

Or whatever.

Comment: on `responseXML` can you do `xmlDoc.document.body.innerHTML` like you could with `DOMParser`?